# copy constructor called wrongly

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    X() { cout<<"default constructor"<<endl; }
    X(const X&) { cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl; }
};

X test(X a)
{
    X y = a;
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    X obj;

    X obj1 = test(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
```

I had compiled the using MinGw compiler.

But, I think the output is wrong.
The copy constructor is called when an object is passed by value, return by value or explicitly copied.
In the above program, the `"copy constructor"` has to be called 4 times.

1. `test(obj)` is called, to copy `obj` to `a`
2. `X y = a` is called, explicitly copied.
3. `return y` is called, `y` is copied to a temporary object, let it be `temp`
4. `X obj1 = temp`, explicitly copied.

Please correct me. Provide your justification too..

Comment: Please add a language tag, if appropriate. You'll also get automatic syntax highlighting ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of the so-called "return value optimization."

The compiler notices that it will have to copy the value of `y` to `obj1`, so instead of returning it by value and copying it to `obj1`, it has the function `test` write to `obj1` directly.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of (N)RVO, aka **Named Return Value Optimization**. The compiler is allowed to elide the copy in the following code:

```
X test(X a)
{
X y = a;
return y;
}
```

If you had written something like this instead:

```
X test(X a)
{
X x = a;
X y = a;
return (true ? x : y);
}
```

(N)RVO would not apply.